# Textinput setValue in onChangeText make "Maximum call stack size exceeded"

Tags: javascript, react-native

My View hierarchy:

```
A extends Component {
   render(this.props.innerView())
}

B extends Component {
   render(
      <A innnerView={this._renderInnerView}/>
   )
}
```

And my innerView contains a TextInput .

In Android , My TextInput is below :

```
<TextInput
                style={{flex: 1}}
                autoCapitalize='none'
                placeholder={strings.addLinkTitleHint}
                keyboardType='default'
                enablesReturnKeyAutomatically={true}
                autoCorrect={false}
                onChangeText={(text) => {
                    console.log("text : ", text);
                    if (this.state.modifyingTitle === text) {
                        return;
                    }
                    this.setState({
                        modifyingTitle: text
                    })
                }}
                underlineColorAndroid='rgba(0,0,0,0)'
                value={this.state.modifyingTitle}
            />
```

I just could get one time log info, and after seconds, I get "Maximum call stack size exceeded" error.

I found the render method in A is called many times, but i do not know how to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

It may have to do with your binding the value to the state, and the fact that `setState` is asynchronous (setting off a chain where `modifyingTitle` is never equal to `text`. If your state is local to the component, you should not have to worry about binding the value of the input to the state, as any change to the input should be reflected in the state anyway (I cannot think of a way it could get out of sync).

Comment: I need to set value to this TextInput according to this.state.modifyingtitle, so I just need to write "value={this.state.modifyingTitle}"  and update this state in onChangeText

Comment: I mean I need set initial value of TextInput

Comment: Maybe pull out the initial value of `modifyingTitle` in the component constructor and put it in a non-state variable, and bind that to the `value`, so that it does not trigger the `changeText` event when it is changed.

Comment: if so, the value would always that variable, it can not be changed

Comment: @yifan_z I am facing the same issue... did you encounter any solution?